# Problem retrieving array of struct with web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

I'm trying to return the struct values contained in array everytime i push a button thet call inserimento and ritornavalore functions.

here is my code in solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


contract M {

    struct Confezione {
        string mar;
        uint256 co;
    }

    Confezione[] public dati;

    function inserimento(string memory m, uint256 c) public {
        dati.push(Confezione(m,c));
    }

    function ritornavalore() public view returns(Confezione[] memory) {
    return dati;

    }
}
```

and here the javascrypt code where i have problems:

```
var codiceAbi = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var connessione = codiceAbi.at(indirizzocontratto);
//richiamo la funzione get
connessione.ritornavalore.call(function (err, variabilediritorno) {
if (err) { console.log(err) }
if (variabilediritorno) {
//mostro l'array a video
document.getElementById("idcontainer").innerHTML = "Valori inseriti fino ad ora: " + variabilediritorno;
}
});
}
catch (err) {
document.getElementById("idcontainer").innerHTML = err;
}
```

in my js i have more code but i think here is the problem when i call ritornavalore.call maybe.

Comment: can you more describe that which type of problem you getting during retrieving array?

Comment: I just can't see data in array @MaheshRajput

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pragma `experimental ABIEncoderV2;`, then you can see this

> Warning: Experimental features are turned on. Do not use experimental
>   features on live deployments.

It means there are still some issues in using `experimental ABIEncoderV2;` in live deployments. Nothing wrong with your solidity code.

For more information, you can see this type of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254328/eth-call-on-web3-interface-returns-null-value-for-contract-function-returning-ar) on stack community.